# Зачем биндить находящуюся в классе функцию в react.js к объкту класса?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть вот такой код:

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOnened: false
    }
  }

  changeMyfield() {
    this.setState({ isOnened: !this.state.isOnened});
  }

  render() {
    let dropdownText;
    if (this.state.isOnened) {
      dropdownText = <div>Text is here</div>
    }
    return(
      <div onClick={this.changeMyfield.bind(this)}> //??????????????
        Hello {dropdownText}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Dropdown />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Если я и так определил `changeMyfield()` в классе `Dropdown` зачем еще делать `onClick={this.changeMyfield.bind(this)}`?

Разве функция не часть класса в котором она определена?

Помогите понять как работает `<div onClick={this.changeMyfield.bind(this)}>`. Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В `onClick` передается ссылка на функцию, а вызов этой функции происходит в другом месте. В JS `this` зависит не от контекста создания функции, а от контекста ее вызова, а т.к. `changeMyfield` будет вызвана в другом контексте и `this` в ней будет ссылать на другой объект.

Есть 2 способа решить эту известную проблему (помимо того что у вас):

1) Использовать новый синтаксис биндинга метода

```
changeMyfield = () => {
    this.setState({ isOnened: !this.state.isOnened});
}
```

2) Сделать биндинг в конструкторе

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOnened: false
    }
    this.changeMyfield = this.changeMyfield.bind(this);
  }
```

После этого функцию можно передавать как `this.changeMyfield` без биндинга.

Comment: Надо заметить, что оба способа лучше чем в вопросе, потому что не создают новую функцию при каждом рендере